# Playa with conditionals and snippets

Tags: channel-entries, playa, conditionals, snippets, advanced-conditionals

I seem to have a problem with Playa + conditionals + snippets. I've emailed P&T since it may be an error in Playa.

I'm trying to accomplish a listings page where the information displayed depends on the membership package of each entry. If statements don't seem to work correctly, perhaps it's the parse order?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="companies" dynamic="no"}

  {!-- this works --}
  {company_membership_package var_prefix="pkg"}
    {pkg:title}
  {/company_membership_package}

  {!-- this works --}
  {company_membership_package}
    {title}
  {/company_membership_package}

  {!-- this fails - nothing displayed --}
  {company_membership_package var_prefix="pkg"}
    {if {pkg:title} == "Premium"}
      {snp_company-listings_Premium}
    {if:elseif pkg:title == "Premium"}
      {snp_company-listings_Premium}
    {/if}
  {/company_membership_package}

  {!-- this fails - outputs {snp_company-listings_Premium} --}
  {exp:playa:children var_prefix="pkg"}
      {snp_company-listings_{pkg:title}}
   {/exp:playa:children}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

{company_membership_package} is a Playa field.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check if your if statements are matched? something like

```
{company_membership_package var_prefix="pkg"}
    {if '{pkg:title}' == 'Premium'}
      ppackage title is Premium
    {if:else}
      package title is not Premium
    {/if}
  {/company_membership_package}
```

By the way, maybe using single quotes as i did might help too

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was as simple as surrounding the field-name by single quotes!